# Cannot find control with name: 'Salutation'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

using reactive forms to get mat-select value but it's giving error Cannot find control with name: 'Salutation':
here is my code

```
  <form [formGroup]="customerService.formModel" autocomplete="off" class="container" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <p class="header-p">CONTACT INFORMATION</p>
  <div class="form-group" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayout.md="column" fxLayout.sm="column">
    <mat-form-field fxFlex="20%" appearance="outline">
      <mat-label class="label-text">Salutation</mat-label>
      <mat-select class="form-control" formControlName="Salutation" placeholder="Salutation">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let salutation of salutations" value="salutation">{{salutation}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-icon class="icon-color" matSuffix>person</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field></div></form>
```

Component file

```
   export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(public customerService :CustomerService ) { }
      ngOnInit(){}
      salutations:string[] =['Mr','Ms'];
}
```

services files

```
  export class CustomerService {
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){ }
formModel:FormGroup =new FormGroup({});
ngOnInit(): void {

  this.formModel = this.fb.group({
    Salutation:['',Validators.required]})
```

what is the problem? i can't seem to understand

Comment: looks like your html is not in proper order, check with that if it works.

Comment: what do you mean? ok i will check HTML to see whats the problem

Comment: i can't find anything is it related to material?why it's not recognize salutation?

Comment: yes formModel is in CustomerService and i injected service class in component constructor with name "customerService".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it the problem is that the formGroup doesnt have Salutation because you are using the ngOnInit hook in the service and with my research it doesnt get called on a service.
Try to log the formGroup and build the form in the constructor

```
export class CustomerService {
formModel:FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
this.formModel = this.fb.group({
 Salutation:['',Validators.required]});
}
```

Should have been a comment but with my reputation i am not able to.

Comment: i did as you told . build the form in constructor but now Giving me this error :  Cannot read property 'formModel' of undefined

Comment: Looks like your service is not properly injected, do you added it into to providers and in your components contructor?

Comment: ok then i dont have any idea sorry, your error message suggests that you access the services formModel property an the service is undefined. Check the naming and log the service in the components constructor. Good luck